# How do I change text in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

As you can see, the error says there is something wrong with:
*See image link*
[Code and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grXT2.png)

```
label.config(text="edited text")
```

My version is: Python 3.11.3, venv

Please reply with the code.

When I ran the code, I wanted to get the text to change.

Comment: Please, post [mre]. Don't post mages of code and error

Comment: urm do you have an answer?

Comment: If you dont post more code, how will we give a proper answer? What is `label` or `chat_history`

Comment: We need to know what `label` is. Maybe it's not what you're assuming it is.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error issued (unknown option (-text)). I wish you had posted the complete code,  Tkinter's Text widget has no option "-text", it's not like a static label, but is rather multi-line text Editor. :

```
import tkinter as tk 
window = tk.Tk()
chat_history = Text(window , height = 10, width = 50) 
yourtxt = """this is a big sample text"""
chat_history.insert(tk.END, yourtxt ) 
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Btw this code doesn't answer the question of how to change/clear the widget's text. In this case `chat_history.delete("1.0", "end")` will clear the `tk.Text`

Comment: Why do you decide it's a `Text` widget?